# Make class dynamic based on a sql query using php

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make the `<a>` class dynamic based on a sql query. Lets say the sql is:

```
SELECT status FROM tbl_person;
while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()){ ?>
<a class="btn-sm"><?php echo $row->status?></a>
```

and I have this wrong code where it should add another `<a>` class that changes the color.

```
if($(this).val() == "happy"){   
    $('a').addClass('btn-yellow');
}
else if($(this).val() == "sad"){
    $('a').addClass('btn-blue');
}
else if($(this).val() == "normal"){
    $('a').addClass('btn-white');
}
```

Please help

Comment: you can apply at server-side create a function for this purpose (same as you did in client side as the concept)

Comment: Like this?

    if($row->status == "happy"){   
    $('a').addClass('btn-yellow');
}

Comment: another question, if the <a> data is inside the <td> tag, what should the condition be?